# About the usage of linux command "xargs"

Tags: linux, shell

I have some file like

```
love.txt  
loveyou.txt
```

in directory `useful`; I want to copy this file to directory `/tmp`.

I use this command:

```
find ./useful/ -name "love*" | xargs cp /tmp/
```

but is doesn't work, just says:

```
cp: target `./useful/loveyou.txt' is not a directory
```

when I use this command:

```
 find ./useful/ -name "love*" | xargs -i cp {} /tmp/
```

it works fine,

I want to know why the second works, and more about the usage of `-i cp {}`.

Comment: what's wrong with `cp ./useful/love* /tmp/`?

Comment: This _will_ work with GNU cp without `-i`, as so: `find ./useful/ -name "love*" -print0 | xargs -0 cp -t /tmp`

Comment: ...note that using xargs without `-0` is dangerous, because it separates filenames with newlines, but a newline is a valid character within filenames on UNIX.

Answer (score 21):

`xargs` puts the words coming from the standard input to the end of the argument list of the given command. The first form therefore creates

```
cp /tmp/ ./useful/love.txt ./useful/loveyou.txt
```

Which does not work, because there are more than 2 arguments and the last one is not a directory.

The `-i` option tells `xargs` to process one file at a time, though, replacing `{}` with its name, so it is equivalent to

```
cp ./useful/love.txt    /tmp/
cp ./useful/loveyou.txt /tmp/
```

Which clearly works well.

Answer (score 12):

When using the `xargs -i` command, `{}` is substituted with each element you find. So, in your case, for both "loveyou.txt" and "love.txt", the following command will be run:

```
cp ./useful/loveyou.txt /tmp/
cp ./useful/love.txt /tmp/
```

if you omit the `{}`, all the elements you find will automatically be inserted at the end of the command, so, you will execute the nonsensical command:

```
cp /tmp/ ./useful/loveyou.txt ./useful/love.txt
```

Comment: when running without -i, the cp command will only be executed once with all arguments passed as a list, no? e.g. try it using 'echo'

Comment: @GrahamGriffiths You are absolutely correct. Updated answer accordingly. Can be demonstrated if piping it to `xargs echo AAA`.

Answer (score 4):

The first example will do this:

```
cp /tmp/ love.txt loveyou.txt
```

Which can't be done, since they attempt to copy the directory `/tmp` and the file `love.txt` to the file `loveyou.txt`.

In the second example, `-i` tells `xargs` to replace every instance of `{}` with the argument, so it will do:

```
cp love.txt /tmp/
cp loveyou.txt /tmp/
```

Comment: when running without -i, the cp command will only be executed once with all arguments passed as a list, no? e.g. try it using 'echo'

Comment: @GrahamGriffiths: you're right.  I was thinking of the example of `xargs -n 1`.  I'll correct this.

Answer (score 4):

xargs appends the values fed in as a stream to the end of the command - it does not run the command once per input value.  If you want the same command run multiple times - that is what the -i cp {} syntax is for.

This works well for commands which accept a list of arguments at the end (e.g. grep) - unfortunately cp is not one of those - it considers the arguments you pass in as directories to copy to, which explains the 'is not a directory' error.

Answer (score 3):

```
find ./useful/ -name "love*" | xargs cp -t /tmp/
```

Comment: -i[replace-str]
              This option is a synonym for -Ireplace-str if replace-str is  specified,  and  for  -I{}
              otherwise.  This option is deprecated; use -I instead.

Comment: good, but you have to edit your question and put it in there, otherwise locked in votes can't be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You might avoid xargs that way:

```
find ./useful/ -name "love*" -exec sh -c 'cp "$@" /tmp' sh {} +
```